# Difference between Simulation and benchmarking

Tags: database, operating-system

Any help would be most welcome...

Thank you ^^

Comment: Also why is a raven like a writing desk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Simulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation) is the imitation of the operation of a real-world process or system over time.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulation) The act of simulating something first requires that a model be developed; this model represents the key characteristics or behaviors of the selected physical or abstract system or process. The model represents the system itself, whereas the simulation represents the operation of the system over time.

[Benchmarking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benchmarking) is the process of comparing one's business processes and performance metrics to industry bests or best practices from other industries. Dimensions typically measured are quality, time and cost. In the process of benchmarking, management identifies the best firms in their industry, or in another industry where similar processes exist, and compare the results and processes of those studied (the "targets") to one's own results and processes. In this way, they learn how well the targets perform and, more importantly, the business processes that explain why these firms are successful.